# Connect to remote mongodb using Unix Domain Socket

Tags: php, mongodb, unix

I am using the PECL extension of Mongoclient in php, which allows me to connect to a MongoDB on compose.io.

I'm using the standard connection to a remote server:

```
new MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@candidate.6.mongolayer.com:10554,candidate.5.mongolayer.com:10690/database?replicaSet=set-xxxxxxxx');
```

However, I have read online that connecting to a Unix Domain Socket can give performance boosts of up to 100x. Currently, the connection to compose.io takes about 1,2 seconds, which is quite long.

How can I setup a Unix Domain Socket to connect to a remote MongoDB server?

Comment: See the operative words here are "unix domain" and "remote" which are both mutually exclusive. "unix domain" means connection on the "same" host only. "Remote" means "networking" and hence TCP sockets. So basically just asked for the impossible. Unless you have another service that "proxies" the unix socket to a TCP socket that is. But that kind of absolves the point.

Answer (score -2):

```
$mongoDns = sprintf('mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s', $user_name, $password, $db_server, $db_port, $db_name);
$options = array('connectTimeoutMS' =>5000 , 'socketTimeoutMS' => 120000);
$conection = new MongoClient($mongoDns,$options);
```

Comment: No, this does not address what the user was asking. It does exactly the same thing as the code posted by OP

Comment: No, but maybe this speeds up the connection?

Comment: @PatrickSteenks You don't seem to understand the comment left by myself earlier. It is not possible to connect to another host over unix domain sockets. They only exist and are visible on the same machine, and therefore only the same machine that the database is running on is where the client needs to be. That is the main reason why any answer is just silly.

Comment: I did understand your answer but thought that the extra parameters mentioned here would speed up the connection.